# Why is my NSArray turning into an NSSet?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsarray, nsset

In Objective-C, using core data, I was fetching entities and they were returned as NSArrays. I realized that I was fetching too often and I could make use of the entity's return values, for example: Customer entity has many Invoices, Invoices have many ItemSolds. Here is some code I'm using:

```
NSError *error = nil;
// fetch all customers
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Customer"
                                           inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
self.fetchedCustomers = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (fetchedCustomers == nil) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR");
}
[fetchRequest release];
// end of customer fetch
```

This is the simple fetch request, and fetchedCustomers is set as an NSArray property. I then use it's functions :

`self.fetchedInvoices = [[customerToView valueForKey:@"invoices"] allObjects];`

This works, and I'm able to display invoice numbers and dates into a table properly. However I then go on to use :

```
self.fetchedObjects = [[fetchedInvoices valueForKey:@"itemsSold"] allObjects];
```

Later, when I try to add totals I do the following:

```
 double price = [[[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Price"] doubleValue];
```

And I get the following error:

```
-[__NSCFSet doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10228f730
```

Why is there an NSSet involved here at all? When I fetched the invoices and items using predicates, I didn't have any problems, but it seemed really inefficient. I would much rather figure out what's going wrong here. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Extra info:

Areas of interest:

```
@interface Invoice : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *itemsSold;
@end

@interface Invoice (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addItemsSoldObject:(ItemSold *)value;
- (void)removeItemsSoldObject:(ItemSold *)value;
- (void)addItemsSold:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeItemsSold:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Comment: What type of property is Price?

Comment: Are you sure?  Try `NSLog ([[[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Price"] class];` right before your line with `doubleValue` in it.

Comment: could you plz show us Invoices.h?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my error. I was sorting the fetchedCustomers into a specific "customerToView". I did not do the same thing with my fetchedInvoices. So my solution as to add :

```
NSManagedObject *invoiceToView = [fetchedInvoices objectAtIndex:(int)[invoicesTable selectedRow]];
```

And use invoiceToView in the place of fetchedInvoices.

Foolish error on my part!

Comment: Yes, the self.fetchedInvoices in your question is an array of NSSet:)

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([[[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Price"] class]);
NSLog(@"class name: %@", className);
```

to make sure what type do you get.

Comment: So I get : `class name: __NSCFSet
2012-05-27 13:10:26.379 InventoryProgram[57463:707] {(
    399,
    499
)}`, but my core data model has it modeled as an NSNumber, and in my header I have :   
`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * Price;`

Comment: Try removing the app from device/simulator, then clean and run again. Just to make sure your model matches the persistent store. I know it would throw different exception, but just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i] seems a NSSet here. [[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Price"] will get all object with key "Price", and it's a NSSet. Good luck!